# What is written after John Lark's name?

Tags: england, palaeography, marriage-records, parish-register

This snippet comes from [Family Search](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.3.1/TH-1-14264-27014-66?cc=1823613) and the parish of Trunch, Norfolk, England.

[image]

I started looking at this record because I believe John Larke was married twice, once to an Elizabeth Vial, and a second time to an Elizabeth Buttle (I guess he had a thing for girls named Elizabeth...). I have two questions from this record that are attempting to prove this theory:

1. What is written after John Larke's name? It looks to me like Single Mem, but that doesn't make any sense to me.
2. Does the Number 2 in the lower left hand corner indicate a second marriage? Or is there any clue that would indicate this is a second marriage?

Comment: I'm curious as to the county and parish this record comes from. I've only ever seen Bachelor and Spinster rather than Single Man and Woman written on English marriage records of this vintage.

Comment: Trunch, Norfolk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The words after John Larke's name are "Single Man" it's just the top of the a doesn't go all the way over. Compare to "Single Woman" after Elizabeth's name. I would interpret it as meaning he was a bachelor rather than a widower.

The "No 2" is I suspect just the number of that entry, but you would need to compare it to the records before and after to be sure.

Comment: You are right. 3 entries, 1, 2, and 3... Thanks!